How to store "export into" command in stored procedure
I am working on SAP HANA BTP Cockpit. I created 1 instance and enter in database explorer. There I created 1 table and transfer that table to AWS S3 bucket using this command:
Export into '<s3-Bucket-Region>://<Access Key>:<secret key>@<s3-bucket-name>/<path/folder>/Filename.csv' from USER.TABLE_NAME;

Now I want to automate this export for everyday or every hour, but I don't find the way.
I tried to store this query in a stored procedure, but I faced a syntax error.

I tried to create a stored procedure as below:
CREATE PROCEDURE EXPORT_TO_S3()
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
AS
BEGIN
    Export into '<s3-Bucket-Region>://<Access Key>:<secret key>@<s3-bucket-name>/<path/folder>/Filename.csv' from USER.TABLE_NAME;
END;

but it gives me error as:

Error: (dberror) [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near into.


I also tried to create an event:
CREATE EVENT "HOURLY_SALES_UPDATE_EVENT"
SCHEDULE START AT '2024-08-12 00:00:00' 
EVERY 1 HOUR
DO
BEGIN
    Export into '<s3-Bucket-Region>://<Access Key>:<secret key>@<s3-bucket-name>/<path/folder>/Filename.csv' from USER.TABLE_NAME;
END;

but it gives me error as:

Error: (dberror) [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "EVENT": line 100 col 7 (at pos 8)


I tried to create job also:
CREATE JOB "HOURLY_SALES_UPDATE"
START TIME '2024-08-12 00:00:00'
RECURRING EVERY 1 HOURS
AS BEGIN
    Export into '<s3-Bucket-Region>://<Access Key>:<secret key>@<s3-bucket-name>/<path/folder>/Filename.csv' from USER.TABLE_NAME;
END;

but it gives me error as:

Error: Error: (dberror) [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "JOB": line 93 col 7 (at pos 8)




Which HANA SQL documentation makes you think that "CREATE EVENT" and "CREATE JOB" are existing and syntactically valid commands?

I want to periodically export my table/Database to S3. Hence, I want to include this 'EXPORT INTO' command in my stored procedure. If you can help me with any documentation, please refer them. I have no experience with SAP.

You can find SAP HANA SQL Reference Guide in the Web easily.

Look at the HANA SQL documentation and you'll see that jobs are not part of SQL and EXPORT INTO is not one of the statements which are permitted in a stored procedure.

You could consider using Dynamic SQL to trigger the export within a stored procedure. However, you should also take note of the best practice to Avoid Using Dynamic SQL.
